# Golang's Bool Type

Tags: go

How do I return a true or false from a function and then check it. This code returns an error: **mismatched types func() bool and bool**

```
func d() bool {
    var e bool
    return e
}

if d == true {
    fmt.Printf("true")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing the actual function to true, not the function result, you need to call the function, e.g.

```
func d() bool {
    var e bool
    return e
}

if d() {
    fmt.Printf("true")
}
```

Comment: Should probably point out that comparing against a bool constant like this is unnecessary. `if d() {` would suffice. Unless of course you really do want to check that it's `true`, and not just truthy, but that's a rare case.